# Вхождение поля А в поле Б на R

Tags: r

Есть два набора данных:

```
x <- data.frame(c("мол", "ден", "свет"))
y <- data.frame(c("молоко", "мебель", "светлый"))
```

делаю кросс джоин, нужно добавить в результат столбец, который показывает,  содержится ли поле из `Х` в поле из `У`.

Comment: Что значит содержится ? Полностью совпадает? или есть в части слова ? Лучше привести итоговый результат которые желаешь увидеть.

Comment: Из вопроса не совсем понятно зачем здесь используются `data.frame`. Решение для векторов и таблиц будет довольно сильно различаться.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Согласно моему комментарию -- не совсем понятно , что хочешь получить .

1) Если у тебя `data.frame` просто текстовые то нужно добавлять `stringsAsFactors=F`

```
x <- data.frame (c("мол", "ден", "свет"),stringsAsFactors=F )
y <- data.frame (c("молоко", "мебель", "светлый"),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Вижу три возможных вариант

-- Если хочешь получить полное совпадение `x` с любым `y`

`x$x1=sapply(x[[1]],function(i) i %in%y)`

-- Если хочешь увидеть наличие `x` в любом кусочке строки `y`

`x$x2=sapply(x[[1]],function(i) grepl(i,y))`

-- Если хочешь увидеть наличие `x`  в `y` по каждой строке 
`x$x3=sapply(1:nrow(x),function(i) grepl(x[i,1],y[i,1]))`

```
> x
  c..мол....ден....свет..    x1    x2    x3 c..молоко....мебель....светлый..
1                     мол FALSE  TRUE  TRUE                           молоко
2                     ден FALSE FALSE FALSE                           мебель
3                    свет FALSE  TRUE  TRUE                          светлый
```